# Enable eth0 without plugging cable to connect to virtualbox bridge

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-manager, 15.04, network-bridge

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 with NetworkManager. I have internet connection on wlan0(dhcp, 192.168.1.0/24) and static ip on eth0(local network, 192.168.124.1/24).

On my virtual machine in VirtualBox i have two interfaces also, eth0 bridged with wlan0(which provides me internet connection, dhcp from router, 192.168.1.0/24) and eth1(which provides me connection to local network, also static ip, 192.168.124.10/24).

When I'm plugged to local network everything works, but when i unplug ethernet cable, NetworkManager brings down eth0 on host and i can't connect to my guest system. I tried setting ip address with ifconfig, it brings up eth0, but I still cant connect to guest system. I noticed, when ethernet cable is plugged, eth0 have RUNNING flag. When I'm setting ip manually, this flag is missing.

Do anyone have idea, how to bring up connection between eth0 on host and eth0 on guest?

Comment: Why do you have two separate networks instead of just using one?  Normally you should have your router provide one network that you can either access via wireless or wired connections.

Comment: It's local network on eth0, separated from network on wlan0

Comment: Yes, I got that.  The question is *why* have two separated networks?

Comment: It's experimental environment for openstack on kvm. I'm using 2nd computer to gain some more resources.